# Is $G(\alpha s)/G(\alpha)$ a probability generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Suppose $G$ is a probability generating function. Let $\alpha\in [0,1]$, then is $\frac{G(\alpha s)}{G(\alpha)}$ necessarily a probability generating function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: a power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ is a probability-generating function if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k=1$ and $\forall k, a_k\ge0$.

If $p(n)$ is the probability-mass function associated to $G$, then $\frac{p(n)\alpha^n}{G(\alpha)}$ is the one associated to $\frac{G(\alpha x)}{G(\alpha)}$. Notice that, since the radius of convergence of $G$ is a priori just $\ge1$, the whole thing might not work for $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Thanks. But why does a probability-generating function $G(x)$  have to satisfy $G(1)=1$? It might be the case that $P(X=+\infty)>0$.

Comment: [The definition I know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Univariate_case) is for natural-valued random variables.

Comment: However, if you have a different definition in which $G(1)=P(X<+\infty)$, then my argument works as long as you substitute "$\sum_ka_k=1$" with "$\sum_ka_k\le 1$" and you either exclude or deal with the case $G=0$.